# Alpine JS global function not defined

Tags: alpine.js

I am using [Alpine JS store()](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store) to make a global function available to toggle a modal status.

**Module**:

```
export default () => ({
    /**
     * @property isOpen - controls the state of the Contact Form Modal
     */
    isOpen: false,

    open() {
        this.isOpen = true
    },

    close() {
        this.isOpen = false
    },
});
```

**Then I use it like**:

```
import modalContactForm from './alpine/modal-contact-form';

// Alpine.store sets data for GLOBAL usage
Alpine.store('modalContactForm', modalContactForm);
Alpine.start();
```

**And with this HTML**:

```
<button x-data @click="$store.modalContactForm.open()"></button>
```

**But I get**:

> Alpine Expression Error: $store.modalContactForm.open is not a function

And I don't know how to debug this situation.

Interestingly, if I pass the object directly into `Alpine.store()`, it works.

```
Alpine.store('modalContactForm', {
        isOpen: false,
    
        open() {
            this.isOpen = true
        },
    
        close() {
            this.isOpen = false
        },
    });
Alpine.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the external module file export the store as a simple object, not as an anonymous function:

```
const modalContactForm = {
    /**
     * @property isOpen - controls the state of the Contact Form Modal
     */
    isOpen: false,

    open() {
        this.isOpen = true
    },

    close() {
        this.isOpen = false
    },
}

export default modalContactForm
```